# Mach-O Linker Error in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Ok so I have 2 projects. I want to import a class file from Project 1 to Project 2. When I import the class file. I get a linker error. Here's what it looks like.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ClassFile1", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ClassFile2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your tags include both ios and osx. if you're building an iOS app, check your Architecture setting in your Xcode project. It shouldn't be x86_64.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, you might have forget adding target to that file. In Xcode, Select the .m file and In the 'File inspector' on the right pane check Target Membership. Ensure that the target is checked for this file.